# How to delete first character in a textfield and update the contents?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a textfield with a default decimal pad. I have created a button and so when the button is pressed, it gets the current numbers in the textfield and makes it into a minus. E.g. if 5 was in the textfield and the button was pressed, -5 would now be in the textfield. I've got this part working but the opposite does not work. So if the user presses the button again, the minus number should now be convertered into a positive number. E.g. -5 should now be 5.

```
if(!(currentSelectedTF.text?.contains("-"))!){
        var selectedtext = "-" + currentSelectedTF.text!;
        currentSelectedTF.text = selectedtext;
    }else{
        var selectedtext = currentSelectedTF.text!.suffix(from: (currentSelectedTF.text?.startIndex)!);
        currentSelectedTF.text = selectedtext;
    }
```

This is the logic im trying to implement when the button is clicked. but I am getting the following error:

```
Cannot assign value of type 'String.SubSequence' (aka 'Substring') to type 'String?'
```

Anyone know why? I am using swift 4

Comment: Not related to your issue but you should check if it `hasPrefix` instead of using `contains`

Comment: About your error you just need to initialize a new `String` with the `Substring` returned by suffix method. `currentSelectedTF.text = String(selectedtext)`

Comment: Last but not least using optional chaining and forcing unwrapping together is pointless. `if !currentSelectedTF.text!.contains("-")` but as I said better to use hasPrefix method  `if !currentSelectedTF.text!.hasPrefix("-")`

Comment: @LeoDabus could you explain how because I've casted selectedtext to a String but still doesn't perform the substring. But there is no errors now

Comment: Swift isn't C.  Drop the semicolons `;`.

Answer (score 1):

Many substring operations in Swift return a new type called `String.SubSequence`, but unfortunately you can't assign that to a `var` of type `String` or `String?`.  You can convert a `String.SubSequence` back to a `String` by passing it to the `String` constructor.

Your line:

```
var selectedtext = currentSelectedTF.text!.suffix(from: (currentSelectedTF.text?.startIndex)!)
```

is not working because you are taking the `suffix` starting with the first character instead of the second. You could fix it by offsetting the index, but `dropFirst()` will do what you want much more easily.

Here is a version of your code that uses `hasPrefix("-")` to look for the `"-"` and uses `dropFirst()` to get rid of the `"-"`:

```
if let text = currentSelectedTF.text {
    if text.hasPrefix("-") {
        // dropFirst() returns a String.SubSequence,
        // so use String() to convert it back
        currentSelectedTF.text = String(text.dropFirst())
    } else {
        currentSelectedTF.text = "-" + text
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you could write the `else` statement.

```
else {
  guard let selectedtext = currentSelectedTF.text,
    let number = Int(selectedtext)
    else { return }
  let newNumber = number * -1
  currentSelectedTF.text = "\(newNumber)"
}
```

PS: also consider the comments: use `hasPrefix` instead of a `contains`. Also, I would probably convert to number and check if it's less than zero. But overall it doesn't matter much I think in this case.